# Is there a name for positive random variables that add up to 1? Is "Convex random variables" phrase appropriate for that?

Tags: probability, distributions, terminology

Is there a name for positive random variables that add up to 1? Is "Convex random variables" phrase appropriate for that? Extending it a bit further, if a weighted Harmonic mean has positive weights chosen randomly such that sum of weights =1, can we say it is a "Harmonic mean with convex weights?"

Comment: Why do you need to specify it explicitly? Weighted means *always* have positive weights that sum to 1 (possibly after a rescaling implicit in their definition), in my experience. I would rather specify "harmonic mean with *random* weights".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The random variables are on a simplex, in this case a probability simplex:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex

With respect to the weighted Harmonic mean, I would say:  "a harmonic mean with weights on a probability simplex"... or, more likely in real life, "a harmonic mean with positive weights that sum to one." :)